# Problems with py2app in Mac OS version 10.14.15 black widow background

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, py2app

I am new in Python, Tkinter etc. And I have a, probably, silly problem.
This script:

```
import tkinter as tk

usrVentana = tk.Tk()
usrVentana.title("Comida")
width = 1200
height = 700
x = 0
y = 115
usrVentana.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))
tk.Label(usrVentana, text="etiqueta").pack()
usrVentana.configure(background='red')
tk.mainloop()
```

When run with python3.8 interpreter all is correct but... If I use py2app to create an app with this setup.py

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['pruebapantalla.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

The only that I have in the screen is a black Window

Black Window:
[image: Black Window]

Comment: it's possible that the error is:  5421 ERROR: Tcl/Tk improperly installed on this system. any suggestion ???   Thank

Answer (score 2):

Same happening for me with py2app 0.26, downgrading to 0.25 seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.
My environments are as follows.

- python 3.8
- py2app 0.20

I confirmed the py2app documentation and found a description as below.
https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#py2app-0-20

- description: Py2app didn’t work with Python 3.8

Therefore, I downgraded Python 3.8 to Python 3.7.
But still, the window was black.

I also downgraded py2app 0.20 to py2app 0.19.
And then, the window was displayed properly.

**conclusion
Please try this version.**

- Python 3.7
- py2app 0.19